# Regular expressions not working as intended in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, re2

I have a task (pushing deliverable to production server) in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` which needs to be limited to branches "hotfix" and "release_candidate", which means branches which name contains one of those strings (we had `"hotfix_2"` at some point, so strictly equal to one of those strings won't do).
I added the following rule:

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /-release_candidate-/ || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /-hotfix-/
```

but I see now that I can't use my task on my "release_candidate" branch. It worked with a branch called `"1283-pouvoir-pusher-en-prod-des-branches-autres-que-hotfix-et-release_candidate"`, which was associated to the merge-request containing all those changes.

I'm not really familiar with RE2 regular expression syntax and resources are not easy to find (I still don't get why they always start and finir with "/" in Gitlab, for example, as it doesn't seem to be part of the [syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)), so I don't get what's the cause of the problem. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your scenario

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /release_candidate|hotfix/
```

Comment: I have already tested my solution expression in gitlab pipeline with the branch naming scenarios and the answer I have given works perfectly fine for matching the two strings which can occur anywhere in the branch name. @Alexis please try my solution and let me know.

Comment: @jessehouwing no, you don't need parens or start/end anchors. When you omit the start/end anchors, the pattern may match on any substring (as the asker requested). [Rule evaluation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#regular-expressions) looks for any match not a full match.